# How recover from `ERROR: ld.so: object '/path/to/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.`?

Tags: apt, dependencies, gtk3-nocsd

In order to prevent CustomerSideDecorations (CSD) I added `nocsd` to my Xubuntu 22.04:
`sudo apt -y install gtk3-nocsd`.

Also, I added this file `~/.xsessionrc` to my home directory:

```
# 2023-11-16 nach dem Vorschlag von https://github.com/PCMan/gtk3-nocsd
#            für  Debian-Linux-Varianten neu erzeugt, damit gtk3-nocsd wirkt:
  if [ -n "$STARTUP" ]; then
    BASESTARTUP=${STARTUP%% *}
    BASESTARTUP=${BASESTARTUP##*/}
    if [ "$BASESTARTUP" = x-session-manager ]; then
      BASESTARTUP=$(basename $(readlink /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager))
    fi
    if [ x"$BASESTARTUP" = x"${BASESTARTUP#gnome-session}" ] ; then
      export GTK_CSD=0
      STARTUP="env LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 $STARTUP"
    fi
  fi
```

After a reboot, I noticed a red cicled exclamation mark-notification on my task bar and looking at its context I saw a lengthy explanation telling me that there are dependency problems to be recovered with `apt` and they relate to
`ERROR: ld.so: object '/path/to/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.`
(the same error message was there several times, the first two letters of the word ERROR were missing on the first one of them.)
I used Synaptic to search for `nocsd` which gave me two hits:

1. `gtk3-nocsd`, it showed the version, but in the last column it was described as `disabled`.
2. `libgtk3-nocsd0`: This entry had reasonable content in all three columns.

Therefore I re-installed `nocsd`, the first one, with Synaptic. After a reboot, `nocsd` was no longer shown as disabled. But the error notification was still present essentially giving me the same as before.
Therefore I checked for the presence of a file `libgtk3-nocsd.so.0` on my system. I found it in three places, two of them related to `snap`. The other one was:
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0`.

First I checked the environment variable `LD_PRELOAD` and I found it to be `/path/to/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0`, which is definitely nonsense. Therefore I added a line
`export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0`
to the end of my `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

After a reboot I wanted to check this environment variable. Before I could enter `echo $LD_PRELOAD` into my terminal window, there already was an error message
`ERROR: ld.so: object '/path/to/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored`
But then `echo $LD_PRELOAD` showed me, that the additional line in `bash.bashrc` had worked to define `LD_PRELOAD`.
Of course, the red circled notification was still on the task bar still giving the same explanation as before.

**What to do next?**

Comment: Does your .xsessionrc file contain literal string `/path/to/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0`? that's just a placeholder that should be changed to the *"full path" of your libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 file*

Comment: Your question was fully justified: In the heat of the moment, I had forgotten to replace the placeholder `/path/to/libgtk3-nocsd.so` with the actual absolute path to the file. After the change and a new login, the error message no longer appeared.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing the placeholder in the definition of `LD_PRELOAD` in `.xsessionrc`, the error message did not appear any longer after reboot.

The file `.xsessionrc` now reads

```
# ***************************** ~/.xsessionrc *****************************
# 2023-11-18 LD_PRELOAD muß den wirklichen absoluten Pfad zu libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 enthalten.
# 2023-11-16 nach dem Vorschlag von https://github.com/PCMan/gtk3-nocsd
#            für  Debian-Linux-Varianten neu erzeugt, damit gtk3-nocsd wirkt:
  if [ -n "$STARTUP" ]; then
    BASESTARTUP=${STARTUP%% *}
    BASESTARTUP=${BASESTARTUP##*/}
    if [ "$BASESTARTUP" = x-session-manager ]; then
      BASESTARTUP=$(basename $(readlink /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager))
    fi
    if [ x"$BASESTARTUP" = x"${BASESTARTUP#gnome-session}" ] ; then
      export GTK_CSD=0
      STARTUP="env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 $STARTUP"
    fi
  fi
```

One has to use the actual position of the file `libgtk3-nocsd.so.0` in the file system!